# How do I transfer Diablo 3 installation from one Mac to another?

Tags: diablo-iii, macos

I bought Diablo 3 via digital download and installed it on my Mac and now I'm trying to get it on my Macbook without having to re-download the entire 7Gigs but I can't seem to find any of the files.  All that was actually installed was the initial Diablo Launcher, which is only 44Mb.  Obviously, there's more to the game than that, but where are the data files stored on the mac?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can always re-download from battle.net and install it again.

Comment: Yeah that's always an option, but I was hoping to avoid another 7+ Gig download.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To transfer your Diablo 3 installation to another Mac, you just need to copy the Diablo III folder in the Applications folder to the new Mac. It should be about 8.5 GB:

[image: Diablo III folder]

If you want to transfer your settings and screenshots, you'll need to copy Diablo III's application support folder as well. You can find it at:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Diablo III

If you're on OS X Lion or later, the Library folder is hidden by default, so you'll need to get to it by opening Finder, going into the **Go** menu, selecting **Go to Folder**, typing in the following:

> ~/Library/Application Support

And pressing the Go button. Copy the entire Diablo III folder there to your new Mac, placing it in the same location.